# How to install P12 certificates in mobile Firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android, certificates

I successfully imported my .p12 certificate to my two android devices (Galaxy Tab E SM-T560 (Spreadtrum SoC) running Kitkat 4.4.4 and Xiaomi Mi A1 Global Version (SD 625)(was) running (Oreo 8.0.0) Pie 9.0 . Now I would like to import the cert  to Firefox on both devices, but I don't actually know what to do. I searched for answers on reddit, but couldn't find a general procedure to do this. Is this even an option in the mobile version of Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, Firefox for Android does not support importing a PKCS #12 certificate.  This is [bug 868370](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=868370).

If you have root access to your device, you can [import it manually](https://fingers.today/tech/import-p12-client-cert-firefox-android) using a Linux computer attached to the phone with `adb`.

If your client certificate came from a `<keygen>` form, you can use the same form in Firefox for Android to generate and install a new certificate directly (skipping the PKCS #12 step).

Comment: Thank you for you information. I'll give it a shot with magisk and se how this work out. I have root access to both devices, but still I'd like to some official way.